# Duplicate results of `ManyToManyField` when using 'through'

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-database

I have two models : *User* and *Article* 
Each *User* can create an *Article* via the selection of one or several *Tag*.

I am using the following representation in my model :

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, default=None)
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article, null=True, blank=True, default=None, through='Tag')

class Article(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, default=None)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Now, I can add users and articles separately. Then I can associate a user to an article.
Say I have only `<user 1>` and  `<article 1>`. I create two distinct tags (done via the admin) :

```
          Tag1
<user 1>  --->   <article 1>
          Tag2
<user 1>  --->   <article 1>
```

I still have only one user, and only one article, but two tags are linking them.
When I query user1.article.all() I expect only one article as result.

**Expected behavior** :

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
print user.article.all()
[<Article: 1>]
```

**Observed behavior**

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
print user.article.all()
[<Article: 1>, <Article: 1>]
```

Anyone knows if this is a bug or if I am querying Django (1.7.1 and 1.7.2) in a bad way ?
If this is normal, how can I remove the duplicates easily ?

[Edit] Opened a ticket in case it is a bug : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24079#ticket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.distinct()`. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

> By default, a QuerySet will not eliminate duplicate rows. In practice, this is rarely a problem, because simple queries such as `Blog.objects.all()` don’t introduce the possibility of duplicate result rows. However, if your query spans multiple tables, it’s possible to get duplicate results when a QuerySet is evaluated. That’s when you’d use `distinct()`.

Comment: Super, that solves the second question.
However, a comment in the man 2 many documentation on that problem should be helpful for such kind of troubles.